# .append in jQuery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending div in existing div and then one more div into append div but it not work for me. what am I doing wrong. please help

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
var cl=$('#free').clone();
var jj=$('.append')
var mm=jj.append('<div class="hii"></div>')
mm.append(cl)
})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:#F00; width:500px; height:50px" id="free"></div>
<a href="#">hide</a>
<div class="append"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not the solution, but you're missing a lot of `;`.

Comment: ; is optional in javascript. And above code is working at my end.

Comment: You're cloning an element with the `id` 'free', so you're creating an element that doesn't have an unique identifier. This isn't valid HTML, so avoid doing that. Instead of `id="free"`, do `class="free"`. Also, what is going wrong with this? Can you create a fiddle or something like that which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Really? It is? Didn't know that.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi I still wonder, whether minifier take care of it. :) But thanks for that info.

Comment: It is optional, but do you really want to leave it off??

Comment: @insertusernamehere: you can try this at your end. :)

Comment: I would not stop appending them. :) But here's a nice article about it: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: Yes its a good practice to always use ;. Its a good programming habit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jj.append('<div class="hii"></div>')` return `jj`, not new div. So use this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    var cl = $('#free').clone();
    var jj = $('.append');

    var mm = $('<div class="hii"></div>');

    jj.append(mm);
    mm.append(cl);
  });
});
```

Comment: @SperanskyDanil & Amit: I can see the same output from both functions.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil: I have seen that but the question is if his code is wrong, then why its giving the correct output? Could you please explain.